# How to determine time taken by an XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, saxon

How can I determine the time taken by an XSLT to execute? I'm currently using saxon xslt processor.

Answer (score 4):

From commandline you can use **-t** parameter

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -t -s:source.xml -xsl:stylesheet.xslt -o:output.xml
```

You obtain information like compilation time, execution time etc.

Take a look at [Saxon documentation](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xsl/commandline.html)

Comment: Thank you Jirka. It helps a lot, is there way to find out time taken by each template or statement etc.,

Comment: Note that for short transformations, the time may be dominated by the "Java warm-up time". To counter this effect, try -repeat:50 on the command line, which executes the transformation repeatedly.